# FileHandle causing memory leak in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsautoreleasepool, filehandler

**The background**

I am working on a project which uses a third party SDK to process files in a particular format. The SDK takes Data as parameter to process. In case of large files, since iOS Data object doesn't support buffered reading, the SDK also allows processing a file chunk by chunk.

**Issue**

I am trying to use `FileHandle` to read huge files chunk by chunk and pass it to the SDK to process. following is the code which I am using:

```
let chunkSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024
let outputFileHandle = try! FileHandle(forReadingFrom: urls[0])
var datas = outputFileHandle.readData(ofLength: chunkSize)
while !(datas.isEmpty) {
    try! $0.process(datas)
    datas = outputFileHandle.readData(ofLength: chunkSize)
}
```

The above piece of code lies in a `subscript` of the SDK's `FileProcessor` object. I tried passing a 5GB file to the above code, but as each chunk it read, it is gradually eating up memory, till it reaches a point where it crashes due to memory issue. I was expecting the `FileHandler` to release already read `Data`.

I tried using `autoreleasepool` like below:

```
autoreleasepool {
    while let data = self.nextData() {
        print("")
    }
}

func nextData(fileHandle: FileHandle, chunkSize: Int) -> Data? {
    return fileHandle.readData(ofLength: chunkSize)
}
```

The above code works like a charm and doesn't clog memory.

However, when I use it in the `subscript`, it shows two compile time errors. For one, as you can see above, there is a mandatory throwable code in the subscript. This cannot be avoided. The two errors I am seeing are shown below:

> Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type
> '((FileEncryptProcess) throws -> Void)?'

The subscript expects a throw, which doesn't get detected due to `autoreleasepool`(That is my assumption reading from the error message)

```
autoreleasepool {
    while let data = self.nextData() {
        try! $0.process(datas)
    }
}
```

Secondly, since the `autoreleasepool` doesn't expect a throw from within its body, the following error is also thrown(Again my assumption reading from the error message):

> Contextual closure type '() throws -> ()' expects 0 arguments, but 1
> was used in closure body

Any approach for reading a file data part by part in iOS is sufficient for me. This is the closest I could reach.